# Identifying font similar to Univers that has this slightly different lowercase character `a`

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I recently came across a book published & printed in 2003 that seems to use a Univers-like font. While trying to figure out what fonts it is using, the only noticeable difference I encountered is in the contour of lowercase character 'a'. Below is an image comparing them side-by-side. Note: the straight-line in contour of 'a' on the left is not a mistake caused by capturing the image as the title is fairly big font-size.

Left: Font used in the book, Right: Univers
[image: image comparing lowercase a of two fonts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original identification looks correct! This looks dead-on for Univers 65. Here's the original metal type. The official digital version you show actually looks a bit weird, the a looks too narrow.[image]

Comment: Thanks Copilot! Yes it’s some cut of Univers, appreciate the confirmation